# How to open an activity from different package (imported module) in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin-android

I have an android project (let's call this Base) in which I have added/imported a new project.
Now, I have to open an activity in the new project (imported module) from the Base project.

How could this be achieved?

From the screenshot,
I want to open **UnityPlayerActivity** in a class under **androidLauncher** package

[image]

I tried using packageManager,

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity");
                if (launchIntent != null) {
                    startActivity(launchIntent);
                }
```

This did not work as it is not getting the package name.

Edit: added root structure for the manifest files
[image: Manifest file structure]

Comment: "How could this be achieved?" -- if `unityLibrary` is a library module, and you add it to the `app` module as a dependency, then you would use `new Intent(context, UnityPlayerActivity.class)`, where `context` is some `Context`, such as an `Activity`. "I tried using packageManager" -- `PackageManager` is for working with other apps on the device.

Comment: I have added the UnityLibrary as a module and as you can see, it has its own manifest too. Now, if I were to use the normal intent to open the UnityPlayerActivity, I have to declare it in the main project's manifest which is not happening because the main project does not know about the UnityLibrary.

Comment: "if I were to use the normal intent to open the UnityPlayerActivity, I have to declare it in the main project's manifest" -- library module manifests get merged into your overall app manifest. So, see if your merged manifest (in the "Merged Manifest" sub-tab of the manifest editor in Android Studio) has an entry for `UnityPlayerActivity`.

Comment: I do not see that. I tried even adding ```tools:node="merge"``` in the library manifest file. Update the description with the root structure of the project.

Comment: Then either you need to talk to the developer of `unityLibrary` and have them add an entry to that library's manifest, or you need to add the entry to your `app` module's manifest. An activity cannot be started, by any possible means, without it being in your app's manifest.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? If so, what is it?

Comment: yes, @Code-Apprentice. It obviously throws a No Class def in Manifest error.

Comment: How could I add an entry to the ```unityLibrary``` activity in the main manifest file? Is there a way now that I have the source added as a lib/module? @CommonsWare

Comment: "How could I add an entry to the unityLibrary activity in the main manifest file?" -- the same way you would for any other activity, by adding an `<activity>` element. You probably have some of these. You should talk to the developer of that library to determine how best to do this.

Comment: The error isn't obvious to me. You might want to edit your question to include this details.